# Python Squeeze Zero Dimension Array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-xarray, dimension

I have an xarray (myxarray) dataarray of shape (0,261, 341) and I need to remove or drop the "0" dimension so that the new shape of the array is (261,341).  The array has dimension "season" and so I have tried

```
newxarray = myxarray.squeeze(dim='season')
```

I receive the error -

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I've also tried --

newxarray = np.squeeze(myxarray, axis=0)

I receive the same error (IndexError)above.

thank you,

Comment: `np.squeeze` is for dimensions of size 1, not dimensions of size 0.  1 * 261 * 341 == 261 * 341, so getting rid of the dimension is just paperwork.  0 * 261 * 341 ≠ 261 * 341, and you can't just create elements out of nowhere.

Comment: how do i remove the "0" dimension? so that I'm left with (261, 341)?

Comment: You can't.  You have absolutely nothing in your array.   Why do you have an array with one of its dimensions being 0 in the first place?

Comment: Well, you can do `np.zeros(myarray.shape[1:])`, which just chops the 0 off the shape and creates a new array of zeros.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: use `myxarray.drop('season')`

Comment: @user2100039 can you print out the array and post it here? There's a big difference between a length-0 non-indexing coordinate on a DataArray and an actual size (0, ...) array, which can't have any data in it. Preferably, [create a minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can use to reproduce the issue and see where you're stuck. Thanks!